# Is it better to put hyphens in a domain name?

Tags: seo, domains, users

Both in terms of `SEO` and user friendliness, is it better to put hyphens in a multi-words domain name or not ?

For example, is `www.stackoverflow.com` better than `www.stack-overflow.com` ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I would avoid hyphens in the domain name. While they are useful in the path for a file or post, they add unneeded noise to the domain itself. Imagine having to spell it out for someone..."stack dash overflow dot com" just doesn't sound right.

On the other hand, there are likely some domains where a well-placed hyphen would be beneficial. For example: **expertsexchange** can be read as **expert sex change**. A hyphen would make a big difference: **experts-exchange**.

In the end, it's up to you, but my instinct is to avoid hyphens in a domain name.

Comment: Another good one: whorepresents.com

Comment: Pen Island dot net is another URL that do with a well placed hypen...

Comment: expertsexchange ? How did you find this example? A good one :-D

Answer (score 11):

Domain name: **No**. (It’s not normal and is harder to remember. However, preference is okay. It doesn’t affect ranking.)

For example,

> http://**webmasters.stackexchange.com**/questions/410/is-it-better-to-put-hyphens-in-a-domain-name

File Location in URL: **Yes**. (It’s easier for people to read.)

For example,

> http: //webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/410/**is-it-better-to-put-hyphens-in-a-domain-name**

Answer (score 8):

**Depends on your user-base**: In Germany everyone would expect hyphens in domain names. In the English-speaking world you should probably avoid them:

1. Nobody expects them there and **mistypes**
2. There is no real right way to **pronounce** it.

On SEO perspective it **doesn't matter**. Both names rank the same.

And of course in doubt you should **purchase both**. Every user gets to the right site.

Comment: Just don't forget to use some URL Rewriter to ensure that they all redirect to the **same** preferred domain, that way "every user gets to the right site" including search engines.

Comment: Definitely. And use **301 redirects** to ensure that the page rank is handed over the preferred domain name.

Comment: And if you have multiple domains mapped to the same document root and are using mod_rewrite to redirect, make sure that you include the redirect in each .htaccess file which has rewrite rules.  I ended up with duplicates once because I expected the redirect to cascade.  I've learned my lesson since and separated the domains into separate document roots.

And if the sites are both answering from the same  you are using mod-rewrite via .htaccess files at different levels in your site hierarchy, make sure that you add the

Comment: It's probably time that has changed this, but it's worth noting that of [Alexa's top 100 sites in Germany](http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries/DE) only 2 actually contain a hyphen in the domain.

Comment: "In Germany everyone would expect hyphens in domain names" — can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

SEO value is not affected by dashes - the search engines ignore them.

But from a user perspective, dashes can make a domain look spammy. Many spammy, exact-match domains have used dashes so they have sort of "poisoned the well".

From [Moz.com](http://moz.com/learn/seo/domain):

> **Top Tips** 
>    - Word Separators: Avoid hyphens. Hyphens detract from credibility and can act as a spam indicator.

If the domain name looks and reads okay without dashes, then I would leave them out.

Answer (score 0):

The question is should we put hyphens in domain names? The answer is if you have them like `www.stack-exchange.com` instead of `www.stackexchange.com`, you will get less traffic because according to SEO practices, domains should have the following properties:

1. Small and memorable
2. Easy to understand
3. Not use hyphens with multi-words for easy indexing