# Are hyphens bad for domain names?

Tags: domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to put hyphens in a domain name ?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/410/is-it-better-to-put-hyphens-in-a-domain-name)

I would just trying to think of a popular website 
that has hyphens in its domain, and honestly - I was having 
problems naming one.

I have a domain name that I have set my mind on, but it's taken. 
However, the same domain with a hyphen in the middle is still available.

What do you think?