# Using a hyphen in the domain name

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, url, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to put hyphens in a domain name ?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/410/is-it-better-to-put-hyphens-in-a-domain-name)

I am looking to buy a domain where the obvious choices have already been purchased.

Example: `domaintest.com` or `domaintest.co.uk`

So, I am looking to mix things up a little with a hyphen.

Example: `domain-test.com` or `domain-test.co.uk`

I have been looking around the web & stack to get a solid picture of why or why not to use hyphens in the domain and am a little confused.

The key factors for me are usability (can users remember the domain, can they type it easily on a phone etc..) and seo.

Ian

Comment: I understand why this has been moved and then closed.  Thanks Admin