# Best SEO URL name for two word searches

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better to put hyphens in a domain name?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/410/is-it-better-to-put-hyphens-in-a-domain-name)

QUESTION: What would work better for a two word search string as "green shoes"?

Acquiring the domain greenshoes.com OR domain green-shoes.com? Or another?

Any other tips on how to score high with two word searches

Help appreciated!

Comment: Good answer to your question just here: [is it better to put hyphens in a domain name][1]


  [1]: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/410/is-it-better-to-put-hyphens-in-a-domain-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, exact-match domains still have an unwarranted ranking weighting applied. Hypenated domains are for those who missed out on the non-hypenated versions, so if you have the opportunity, then get the non-hyphenated one.

Besides the domain (and on-page factors like page titles, content etc), it will be natural back-links that contain that phrase (or related) to your site that works best - hence Adobe Acrobat Reader ranking #1 for 'click here' (since every link has that anchor phrase).

Comment: and with natural back-links you mean other sites that link to you (not on your own site)

Answer (score -1):

Get them both and set your dns/web server up so they both point to the same website.

But to be honest, SEO goes way beyond just the url name and I would question just how much the URL actually is counted in the algorithm.  Things like page titles, headings, links to your site(s), meta tags and quite a few other factors are part of the equation.

Comment: Would you use a domain pointer? But also I have come to realize that request URL's or pages (after the domain) are lost when using pointers ....greenshoes.com/specials would then result in theshoeshop.com (withour request params)

So, what would be the best method for SEO and google liking and crawling this?